# How to split a table into a set of unique values, with another set of leftover duplicates

Tags: sql, oledb

I haven't used SQL in years, and this problem is a bit beyond me.
I have a set of dated entries in an Excel sheet that I'm querying with a oledb connector. If some fields (in the eg, Name, Email and Fruit) match another entry, they are considered duplicates. But they have other fields that may be unique.

I need to process this set so that I have:

(1) A set of unique entries, with the earliest instance of the duplicate entries. If they have the same date (which can happen), it doesn't matter which one I have (but one should be in the unique set, the others in the duplicate set)

(2) A set of the later/leftover duplicate entries

As an example data set. Given:

```
Name            Email                   Comment     Fruit       Date        Foo     
John Smith   johnsmith@mail.com     lorem ipsum     apple       2019-05-06  bar
Joe Bloggs   -                      dolor sit amet  banana      2019-05-28  bar
John Smith   johnsmith@mail.com     adipiscing elit apple       2019-05-16  fizz
Lawry Tripp  -                      sed do eiusmod  pear        2019-05-06  fizzbuzz
Mike Davos   mikedavos@mail.com     tempor incididunt pear      2019-05-28  bar
Mike Davos   mikedavos@mail.com     ut labore et    pear        2019-05-28  foo
Talor Quimby -                      dolore magna    kumquat     2019-05-16  foobar
Gob Bloggs   -                      dolor sit amet  banana      2019-05-28  bar
```

I need the sets

(1)

```
Name            Email                   Comment     Fruit       Date        Foo
John Smith   johnsmith@mail.com     lorem ipsum     apple       2019-05-06  bar
Joe Bloggs   -                      dolor sit amet  banana      2019-05-28  bar
Lawry Tripp  -                      sed do eiusmod  pear        2019-05-06  fizzbuzz
Mike Davos   mikedavos@mail.com     tempor incididunt   pear    2019-05-28  bar
Talor Quimby -                      dolore magna    kumquat     2019-05-16  foobar
Gob Bloggs   -                      dolor sit amet  banana      2019-05-28  bar
```

and

(2)

```
John Smith  johnsmith@mail.com  adipiscing elit apple   2019-05-16  fizz
Mike Davos  mikedavos@mail.com  ut labore et    pear    2019-05-28  foo
```

So far I've been able to get

(a) a set of unique entries

(b) a set of all the duplicates

But I'm stuck in writing a query that given (b) will extract the earliest Date from each group and add it to (a) (therefore creating the first output set that I require). I'm assuming that whatever that query is, I can subtract its results from (b) to get the leftover duplicates.

(Sorry, I tried to include the SQL to create the test table, but when included SO flags the post as spam and won't let me post it)

This is the query I use to get the set of unique entries (a):

```
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM data
    GROUP BY
        Name, Email, Fruit
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) = 1
  ) t1
    JOIN
    data t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Email = t2.Email AND t1.Fruit = t2.Fruit
```

And the inverse query to get the duplicates (b):

```
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM data
    GROUP BY
        Name, Email, Fruit
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) >= 2
  ) t1
    JOIN
    data t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Email = t2.Email AND t1.Fruit = t2.Fruit
```

From what I can find this seems to be something called a groupwise-minimum problem. But I'm at the limits of my SQL. The solutions I've seen discussed use common table expressions/CTE, but I don't think my environment (oledb) supports them.

I feel like I'm close, I just need to query the duplicate set correctly and join it with the unique set/subtract it from itself to get to my end results.

What query can I write to correctly split that set of duplicates?